# ggplot2 geom_hex w/ two data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a hexbin plot of food poisoning data. I can do this very easily with ggplot2 and geom_hex...

```
ggplot(df) + geom_hex(aes(x=longitude, y=latitude))
```

See code here... https://gist.github.com/corynissen/5823114

But, this will plot the frequency of food poisonings only, and this will be misleading as there will be more food poisonings reported in areas with more restaurants. So, I'd like to normalize that using the restaurant license data.

Basically, for every bin, I want the count of df divided by the count of lic (see data / code in link).

Comment: I was going to give this a try, but the data file seems to be huge and the server slow. Provide smaller data sets.

Answer (score 0):

If a heat map is also acceptable for you, here is my dirty solution:

```
# we don't want missing values in lat or lon
lic <- subset(lic, !is.na(longitude) & !is.na(latitude))

# get the x and y ranges for the union of both data sets
xmin <- min(c(df$longitude, lic$longitude))
xmax <- max(c(df$longitude, lic$longitude))
ymin <- min(c(df$latitude,  lic$latitude))
ymax <- max(c(df$latitude,  lic$latitude))

# set the number of bins and get x and y break points
n_bins  <- 30
xbreaks <- seq(xmin, xmax, length=(n_bins+1))
ybreaks <- seq(ymin, ymax, length=(n_bins+1))

# get the 2d histogram of the food inspections set
v1 <- cut(df$longitude, breaks=xbreaks)  # creates a factor of length nrow(df)
v2 <- cut(df$latitude,  breaks=ybreaks)  # creates a factor of length nrow(df)
A1 <- as.numeric(table(v1,v2))           # of length n_bins*n_bins

# get the 2d histogram of the business licenses set
v1 <- cut(lic$longitude, breaks=xbreaks) # creates a factor of length nrow(lic)
v2 <- cut(lic$latitude,  breaks=ybreaks) # creates a factor of length nrow(lic)
A2 <- as.numeric(table(v1,v2))           # of length n_bins*n_bins

# let's normalize the data
A3 <- A1 / A2
A3[is.infinite(A3) | is.na(A3)] <- 0  # 2 values were infinite!?

# create the final data set in a very very dirty way...
df2 <- data.frame(longitude = rep(seq(xmin, xmax, length=(2*n_bins+1))[seq(2, (2*n_bins+1), by=2)], times=n_bins), latitude = rep(seq(ymin, ymax, length=(2*n_bins+1))[seq(2, (2*n_bins+1), by=2)], each=n_bins), count=A3)

# ...and visualize it
ggplot() +
   geom_tile(data=df2, mapping=aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, fill=count))
```